# using OR operator for each element of an array in single "when" function of pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I have an array of columns

```
DiversityTypes = ["ABC","EFG","LMN","XYZ"]
```

I want to work on a Pyspark dataframe where I create a new column named "`Is_Diversified`" and set its value `Yes` ,`No` using **OR operater** on the values of each element of `DiversityTypes`  above mentioned, in a single `when` function as below:

```
    p_df = p_df.withColumn('Is_Diversified', f.when(f.col("ABC") == 'Y'|\
                                                    f.col("EFG") == 'Y'|\
                                                    f.col("LMN") == 'Y'|\
                                                    f.col("XYZ") == 'Y'),lit("Yes")).otherwise(lit("No")))
```

into something this, where we iterate over each element of the array and simultaenously have OR operator applied to it

```
for diversity in DiversityTypes:
    p_df = p_df.withColumn('Is_Diversified', f.when(diversity) == 'Y'),lit("Yes")).otherwise(lit("No")))
```

I can't apply the logic here, please help, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `functools.reduce` with the [bitwise or operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

p_df = p_df.withColumn(
    'Is_Diversified', 
    f.when(
        reduce(
            or_, 
            [f.col(c)=="Y" for c in DiversityTypes]
        ), 
        f.lit("Yes")
    ).otherwise(f.lit("No"))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this? Make an array and check the array has any `Y`.

```
DiversityTypes = ["ABC","EFG","LMN","XYZ"]

df.withColumn('Is_Diversified', when(lit('Y').isin(*map(col, DiversityTypes)), "Yes").otherwise("No")).show()

+---+---+---+---+--------------+
|ABC|EFG|LMN|XYZ|Is_Diversified|
+---+---+---+---+--------------+
|  Y|  N|  N|  N|          true|
|  N|  N|  N|  N|         false|
|  Y|  Y|  Y|  Y|          true|
+---+---+---+---+--------------+
```

Comment: that's exacltly how I would do it ;)

Comment: Thank you, @Lamanus. This is right but I wanted the 'Is_Diversified' as Yes, No. Appreciate your help truly!

Comment: a bit modified, check it