# Pyspark equivalent of pandas all fuction

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe df:

```
   A    B     C     D
 True  True  True  True
 True  False True  True
 True  None  True  None
 True  NaN   NaN   False
 True  NaN   True  True
```

Is there a way in pyspark to get a fifth column based on rows A, B, C, D not having the value False in them but returning an int value or 1 for True and 0 for false. Hence:

```
   A    B     C     D     E
 True  True  True  True   1
 True  False True  True   0
 True  None  True  None   1
 True  NaN   NaN   False  0
 True  NaN   True  True   1
```

This can be acheived in a pandas dataframe with the function `df.all().astype(int)`.

Any help for a pyspark equivalent would be most appreciated, please.

Comment: boolean columns cannot contain NaN in spark. Can you post an example code that creates your dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The dataframe values are all fake. Could you please work on a solution assuming that all of the None and NaN values are True? Many thanks

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63634987/5858851 - just use all the columns in the reduce. `df.withColumn("E", reduce(or_, [col(c) for c in df.columns]).cast('int'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have anything to test, but try the code below:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'E',
    (
        (F.greatest(*df.columns) == F.least(*df.columns)) & 
        (F.least(*df.columns) == F.lit(True))
    ).cast('int')
)
```